# How to make images look and feel like buttons

Tags: wordpress, user-interface, responsive-design

I have created a page containing a list of items. Each item has an image corresponding to it which when clicked directs the user to a new page containing more information about the item. For some reason, when I asked my friends to go through the site, most of them thought that these were non-clickable images. What can I do to make it more obvious that a user can actually click on the image? Below you can find a screenshot of the page I am talking about and this is a [link](https://thechallengeclub.wordpress.com/challenges/) to the actual page. Thanks in advance for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1.You can add a title attribute to a link, like this:

```
<a title="Read more" href="https://thechallengeclub.wordpress.com/challenge-1-just-water/">
```

Then when user hover over the image a tooltip will appear:
[image]

2.You can add an easy to see "More" button. It's up to you where you add this button, but it may be necessary to change the layout a little bit.

For example:

[image]